# How to create a nasm libraries monorepo

Tags: assembly, nasm

In the project im developing with nasm I realized that it may be a better idea to move some parts of the code to external libraries (e.g argparser functionality).

Currently I have something like:

*argparser.inc*

```
extern argparse

struc command 
  .arg_count:   resq    1
  .name:        resq    1
  .fn:          resq    1
endstruc
```

*argparser.asm*

```
%include "argparser.inc"
%include "linux.inc"
%include "string.inc"

section .text

;;
; Parse arguments, if it does not match exits.
; @param RDI - argc
; @param RSI - argv
; @param RDX - commands
; @param RCX - commands_help
; @return RAX - pointer to the command struct
;;
argparse:
global argparse:function
...
```

Using `%include "argparser.inc"` from other files to just include it.

As I said this seems to me more like a dependency than code that should be specific to this project. Therefore I firstly thought of having an argparse library repository and using a github submodule so it's added to something similar to `/myproject/libs/argparse/argparse.inc` so I would just update `%include "argparser.inc"` with `%include "libs/argparse/argparser.inc"` (and maybe update my `Makefile`). After that realized that I currently have more potential functionalities like `string.asm`/ `string.inc` so why not just having a monorepo with all my nasm libraries since they may come handy in later projects, right?

After all that realized about a big problem. Libraries among my monorepo may have dependencies between them. For instance `argparser` library depends on  `string` library. One possible solution would be to go back to a single repository per library and follow the same approach of using github submodule on external dependencies (which may be another of my libraries), ending up in something like:

```
.
└── myproject/
    ├── arun
    ├── ...
    └── libs/
        └── argparser/
            └── libs/
                └── string
```

That reminds me to npm `node_modules`. However it may end up in a "libs hell".

Is there is a way to create a libraries monorepo, with the structure shown below where there may dependencies among libraries inside the monorepo and allow using something like git submodule to include that library and it's dependencies (similarly to package managers for higher level languages).

```
.
└── lib-monorepo/
    ├── argparser/
    │   ├── argparser.inc
    │   ├── argparser.asm
    │   ├── Makefile
    │   └── README.md
    ├── string/
    │   └── ...
    └── ...
```

Comment: This is a software design question. nasm has `-I` to let you specify where it should look for includes. That would give you the flexibility to put library sources where you want. But I would put each library under its own sub folder along with a makefile to assemble it. The set of public names in the final `.o/.obj` file would be its public interface and a client application would just need to include the object files of each dependency. That's a form of dependency inversion for assembly (you can link with another implementation for `string.o` and `argparser.o` would still link`).

Comment: You'd need to use `EXTERN` to introduce a name declared in another object file.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Using EXTERN seems like the way to go. However, i https://github.com/prefapp/firestarter/pull/525/commits/72e98a8212035eb4c428aaae7da1700982f5afb5would like to have a library than among others stuff it has some nasm macros that i would like to use from the binary including that dependency, the same thing with nasm strucs, can extern make that work?